# Including PHP files with Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to "include" a php script into one of my views (landing.blade.php).

The script is in:

```
/laravel-master/public/assets/scripts/config.php
```

When I try to include this code in the view:

```
<?php include_once('/assets/scripts/config.php'); ?>
```

I get the error:  `include_once(/assets/scripts/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

This is on localhost using MAMP.  I'm not sure if there is a different set of rules I need to use with Laravel 4 to include a php file.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: `/assets/scripts/config.php` means it's at the root of your OS. Use an absolute path or change it to relative.

Comment: Could you expound on that?  What would the relative path look like?  ../assets/scripts/config.php ?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 50):

First, it's not really recommended that you keep your PHP files in the `public` directory, they should be kept inside the `app` folder. I'd suggest you create a folder inside `app`, something like `includes` and put your files there. Then, you include it, do:

```
include(app_path().'/includes/config.php');
```

Although, since it looks like you're trying to load some configuration files, I'd recommend you also check out Laravel's own way of handling configurations. For instance, if you created a `myapp.php` file inside the `app/config` folder, Laravel would handle it automatically for you, as long as you'd have some key-value pairs, like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'name'     => 'Raphael',
    'gorgeous' => true
];
```

You could then retrieve these values using the `Config` class:

```
Config::get('myapp.name'); // Raphael
```

This is a better solution because you can also take advantage of Laravel's [environment configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: I am trying to load this configuration file for a Facebook login.  Contains appID, secret, etc...  Does this change your answer at all?

Comment: Well, if you can't change the code that will use the configuration file, then it renders the 'using Laravel's built in configuration stuff' invalid, but the rest still counts.

Comment: Where do I put the: $app = app();
include($app['path.app'].'/includes/config.php');

in my view?

Comment: Better yet, you can use `include(app_path().'/includes/config.php');` in your view.

Comment: Well, if you are including this on all requests, put it on `app/start/global.php`, at the end. Else, you'll have to find the best place to do it.

Comment: `app_path()` was introduced in **Laravel 4**. Use `path('public')` in **Laravel 3**

Comment: in laravel 5.1 app_path(). is the root/app directory, but the recources folder is root/resources, how would you go 1 step up?

Comment: @davejal `app_path().'/../resources'`? You most likely shouldn't include anything on the `resources` folder, though.

Comment: @mobis: why not? I need to use a wsdl file. Where else would you recommend placing this the file?

Comment: No, that's fine for a `.wsdl` file. You just won't actually `include` it, since it's not PHP, probably just pass it as a parameter to a function.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 2):

> You can use includes in HTML forget about concatenation

```
@include('foldername.filename')

@include('filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way:

```
require 'file path';
```