# PHP Notice: Constant FLD_EMAIL already defined laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a file called `db-constant.php` in conifg directory in laravel , this file contains my constants,then i added this line `require_once 'db-constants.php';` in `app.php` ,the problem is where i type php artisan cache:clear or any command this message will appear

PHP Notice:  Constant FLD_EMAIL already defined in /var/www/html/test/config/db-constants.php on line 1

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Why exactly did you add `require_once`? Did you read Laravel's docs at all? It's sufficient to just add the file to `config/` directory, you don't have to require anything.

Comment: Few things here, first a way to include files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159046/including-php-files-with-laravel-framework

Comment: Secondly, why different file for constants ?

Comment: @mjh because when i deploy my project ,undefined constant message will appear

Comment: @wahdan you don't **need** constants. I wrote an answer, I can tell you didn't read anything about Laravel's configuration - I suggest that you do.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave because it contains large number of constants, is there a better way?

Comment: did you check my posted link above ?

Comment: Wahdan, those constants didn't appear out of nothing. You wrote them. And you wrote them because you didn't read how Laravel's configuration works. Question is - **WHY DID YOU USE CONSTANTS** at all. And the answer is *because you didn't read the docs* so you thought you should use constants. Now, there's a solution, read my answer please and then check how Laravel deals with configuration and try to implement it. Good luck to you, your project and your clients! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Laravel`, you don't have to use `require_once` or it's counterparts. `composer`'s autoloading is used for everything, and configuration files are loaded automatically. What you have to do is read the docs about configuration, place the file in `config/` directory and return an `array` with configuration values.

Now, what it seems (to me at) is that for some odd reason you want to use constants instead of Laravel's mechanism for accessing configuration values. In that case, you:

1.) DON'T place anything in `config/` directory

2.) DON'T manually `require_once` anything

3.) DO use Composer's autoloading capabilities

### How to load a file with constants in Laravel

1.) create `app/MyConstants` directory.

2.) create your file, let's call it `constants.php`. Path is: 
`app/MyConstants/constants.php`

3.) Add your `define` code

4.) Open `composer.json`

5.) Find `"autoload"`

6.) Look for `"files"` under `"autoload"`. If it doesn't exist, create it.

7.) Add the list of files you want to include automatically

Your `"autoload"` in `composer.json` should look like this:

```
"autoload": {
  "files": ["app/MyConstants/constants.php"]
}
```

In terminal, type `composer du` or `composer dump-autoload`. It will re-create autoloader and automatically include the file with your constants.

Remove `bootstrap/cache` so you can use `artisan` again.

Now you can:

1.) Have a place where you can define constants

2.) Avoid manually requiring files

Personally, I don't see a reason for this, but then again - I'm just a human, I've no clue about anything in the grand scheme :)

Comment: Well this is true. Following the documentation is an ideal way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this docs first https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration. As well as the rest of the documentation for Laravel. How to use config files:

1. Create your own file `db-constant.php` in config directory.
2. Fill it as you need. For example

   ```
   return [

       'FLD_EMAIL' => 'your-field-here',

   ];
   ```
3. Use it wherever you need

   ```
   $email = config('db-constant.FLD_EMAIL');
   ```

It's all.