# Laravel PHP require() fails even though file_exists() returns true

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing an extremely puzzling issue on Centos 7:

1. `file_exists(example/file.php)` returns `true`
2. However, `require(example/file.php)` throws an `ErrorException` of`No such file or directory`
3. The above happens only inside a Laravel command
4. If I were to create a standalone script with 2 lines, e.g. `test.php` with `file_exists()`, followed by `require()`, it runs with no issues.
5. Further, `example` folder is a symbolic link to a virtualbox mount folder
6. I have the exact same setup in Centos 6.4 with no issues

To be safe, SELinux has been disabled. Where do I even start? Thank you.

Code as requested:

```
$a = "example/file.php";
if (file_exists($a)) echo "found";  // "found" is echoed
require($a);    // throws ErrorException
```

## Update

I posted this question after spending a night on it. After more intensive digging, I realized that if I set a xdebug breakpoint at `require()` and continue running, it works.

This leads me to believe that it is a caching issue on my CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core) and I have posted an issue here https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager/issues/101, note that `file.php` in my example is a newly downloaded and extracted file.

Comment: Please provide actual code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including PHP files with Laravel framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159046/including-php-files-with-laravel-framework)

Comment: I dont think you can  `include` or `require` non php files see this doc  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php , specifically, this statement int the examples: `// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';` Not 100% certain this applies, honestly never had the need to `include` a non php file before

Comment: Since this is a text file and not php, could you use `file_get_contents` instead?

Comment: My apologies, it is a PHP file